# Pandas read_html equivalent for a lxml table

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

Hi I have about 10 tables which I have used lxml to classify.

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import lxml
>>>root = lxml.etree.HTML(htmlcontent)
>>>tables = root.findall('.//*[@id="info-container"]/table')
>>>readabletables = tables[::2]
>>>len(readabletables) = 5
>>>readabletables[0]
<Element table at 0x105241e60>
```

I want these 5 tables to be read and interpreted by pandas just like `pd.read_html`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: have you seen this? http://timhomelab.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-read-xml-file-into-dataframe.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am able to now answer my own question and maybe this can be of assistance to others.

I tried modifying the read_html source code in pandas without much success because of some recognition issues. Nonetheless the answer is much simpler than you might think.

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import lxml
>>>root = lxml.etree.HTML(htmlcontent)
>>>tables = root.findall('.//*[@id="info-container"]/table')
>>>readabletables = tables[::2]
>>>len(readabletables) = 5
```

^ This is what we have already established.

Now in order for pandas's `read_html` to recognise a lxml table, the table need to be converted in to html. To this we do the following:

```
>>>etree.tostring(readabletables[0],method='html')
'<table... table>'
```

To convert all the tables in to pandas df inside a list:

```
>>>pd_tables = [pd.read_html(lxml.etree.tostring(table,method='html')) for table in readabletables]
>>>len(pd_tables)
5
>>>type(pd_tables[0])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Mission accomplished.